# Laravel Eloquent double value stored in database returned rounded

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, double

I have following value stored in MySQL database `23456789123,45678` and when I'm getting this value using magic variable I'm getting `23456789123,457` as a value.

I have tried `$cast` variable in Model:

```
protected $casts = [
  'previous_value' => 'double(16,5)',
]
```

but that did not helped. Much appreciate on any help in this regards.

Comment: How your db structure?

Comment: it is sotred as double(16,5) ie:
`$table->double('previous_value', 16, 5)->nullable();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with Laravel, it is actually PHP that is rounding this. In the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) you can see that the default precision is **14**, which you are currently exceeding.

> ```
> Name      |   Default |   Changeable   |
> precision |   "14"    |   PHP_INI_ALL  |
> ```
>
> The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
>   -1 means that an enhanced algorithm for rounding such numbers will be used.

Try the following and see if it resolves the issue:

```
ini_set('precision', 17);
ExampleModel::find($id)->previous_value;
```

You can see someone else has answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33093507/laravel-eloquent-truncates-the-data-type-double).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I could not find right keywords to find that but anyway I will double check.

Comment: What I did is I have added following method in my Model:
`public function getPreviousValueAttribute($value) { ini_set('precision', 17); return $value; }` . That will definitely bring correct value in output. Ofcourse I will put that in configuration in future. @alex-harris thanks for pointing me to solution!

Comment: More general solution would be to put that into `constructor` like this: `public function __construct() { ini_set('precision', 17); parent::__construct(); }`.