# Laravel Eloquent float value stored in database returned additional numbers

Tags: php, laravel, floating-point

This is my migrations

```
$table->float('odd', 10, 0)->nullable();
```

I save odd value in db as `4.45` but it returned as `4.45000000000000017763568394002504646778106689453125` 
I look this post [Laravel Eloquent double value stored in database returned rounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50627376/laravel-eloquent-double-value-stored-in-database-returned-rounded)

but that is not solve my problem. Also problems only occur in server 
How can solve it?

Comment: Can you show how you're retrieving the value from the database?

Comment: @RossWilson Like `UserTip::find(1, ['odd']);`

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a little late, but maybe this can help someone.

[PHP7.1 json_encode() Float Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981409/php7-1-json-encode-float-issue)

**TLDR**

The problem is in serialize_precision in php.ini
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Mine was set to 100 and it caused me the same problems. Setting to -1 resolved it.

Comment: Did you know that if a question can be answered by another answer on Stack Overflow we do not usually add a new answer? I know you don't have enough reputation to comment, but we post the link in a comment and close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Another reason to hate PHP. I rounded my floats using the `round` function, yet `json_encode` will mess them up.